# Configure a TraceSource with two TraceListeners and different filters in app.config

Tags: c#, .net, logging, app-config, tracelistener

I am using the .net framework classes `TraceSource` and `TraceListener` for logging. They are configured in my `app.config` file. The same TraceSource may log to multiple different TraceListeners writing to different logfiles.

Now I want to filter TraceEvents from a specific TraceSource, but only for one TraceListener and not the other

In my `app.config` file I have some shared TraceListeners:

```xml
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="log1" type="MyTraceListener,MyAssembly"  initializeData="log1.log"/>
  <add name="log2" type="MyTraceListener,MyAssembly"  initializeData="log2.log"/>
  <add name="logWarning" type="MyTraceListener,MyAssembly"  initializeData="logWarning.log">
      <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" initializeData="Warning"/>
  </add>
</sharedListeners>
```

And I have configured some TraceSources

```xml
  <source name="Foo" switchValue="All">
      <listeners>
        <add name="log1"></add>
        <add name="log2"></add>
        <add name="logWarning"></add>
      </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="Bar" switchValue="All">
      <listeners>
        <add name="log1"></add>
        <add name="log2"></add>
        <add name="logWarning"></add>
      </listeners>
  </source>
```

The Listener `logWarning` only receives TraceEvents with severity `warning` or above, from all sources. So far so good.

Now I want to configure the Listener `log2` to receive only warnings from the source `Foo`, but still everything from source `bar`. The Listener `log1` should also still receive everything from `Foo`and `bar`.

What is the corrrect app.config syntax for this?

Comment: It looks like you are using custom listeners, you might be able to do a custom trace filter, override ShouldTrace and filter based on the TraceSource, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracefilter.shouldtrace(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: that might work as a last resort, but I am mainly looking for the correct syntax to set this inside the app.config file. I hope i am not wrong in thinking this is possible.